# Load a package and use it's functionality inside C#

Tags: packages, .netlink

I am trying to make a windows *C#* form which uses some functions that I wrote inside *Mathematica*.

Suppose that we have the following package:

```
BeginPackage["second`"];
Begin["`Private`"];

SecondDegre[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{delta, x1, x2},
     delta=b^2-4*a*c;
     x1=(-b + delta^0.5)/(2 a);
     x2=(-b - delta^0.5)/(2 a);
     {x1,x2}
];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

I already tested this package in *Mathematica* - it works, successfully made a connection *C#* to *Mathematica* by adding reference and tested this example:

```
using Wolfram.NETLink;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Expr symbolPlus = new Expr(ExpressionType.Symbol,"Range");
     Expr e1 = new Expr(symbolPlus, 1, 4,1);
     IKernelLink ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
     ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();

     // ml is a KernelLink
     string result = ml.EvaluateToOutputForm(e1, 0);
     textBox3.Text = result ;

     ml.Close();
}
```

The output after execution is:

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

My question is :
How can I run the *Mathematica* package inside *C#* in order to use the `SecondDegre` like i have used the `Range` in the previous example?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can just do a Get[] or Needs[] to load the package...BTW test this without .NetLink first to make sure you have the directory issues figured out

After your package is loaded, you should be able to evaluate SecondDegre[] just like accessing functions inside packages from inside Mma.

Ref: http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/packages.html

Comment: I already tested this before, and unfortunately it doesn't work!